# iOS app disconnecting from BLE device even with characteristic changes

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, disconnect

I have an iOS app that I connect to a custom BLE device.

We are sending data constantly from the device by updating a characteristic that the iOS app has subscribed to.

It is my understanding that as long as the characteristic is updating its value we should not disconnect.

The device does disconnect after about a minute. It is almost exactly the same amount of time.

We also have an Android app and it does not disconnect. It will run forever as long as the device is updating its characteristic.

The message that I see in the log is simply:

```
BTServer[6940] <Error>: Disconnected unexpectedly from device "558B27AF-1AA6-422E-A770-6C3202D2BA8C" with error 759
```

What would cause an iOS app to disconnect in this situation? How can I diagnose the issue?

Comment: I can't find any reference to error 759, but your app should always be prepared for disconnections; that is the nature of Bluetooth.  Peripherals can go out of range etc (even though that isn't happening in this case).  Just reconnect to the peripheral and carry on

Comment: It is not a problem of being able to handle it. It is the fact that I am right next to the device and it is not initiating the disconnect as far as I can tell. I am actually handling the disconnect and reconnecting, but it means the data on the app screen keeps having pauses when it happens. Like I said in the post, when I use the same device with Android under the same circumstances it will run forever. So the question is why does iOS keep disconnecting at a pretty consistent interval and how do I stop it?